# Can the offer to move to jobs be made more clear?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

When I visit someone else's CV, I get this prompt:

[image: Hey look! My personal email!]

My immediate thought was, "How did this guy get my email address?" My second thought was, "Oh wait. I'm about to take over this person's CV." For sanity, I used an incognito window and discovered this was just a general offer to me and not related to the CV I happened to be reading:

[image: The text is aligned funny here for some reason.]

Can this offer be made more clear when visiting someone else's CV?

Comment: Is this showing up with the Developer Story?

Comment: Now everyone has your email address...

Comment: @Siguza: Feel free to [write if you get work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_and_Ray#Radio).

Comment: This question is not clear to me due to 2 problems: First: could you please provide a link where I can see this info? Could not find "when visiting someone else's CV". Second: these images don't have [freehand circles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138031/is-there-a-joke-about-freehand-circles-that-im-oblivious-to).

Comment: @Zanon: 1) Click the link on the first image. That's the page. 2) The images _do_ have freehand circles but they are too small to be seen at this resolution.

Comment: @bluefeet: No. Only on the old Careers CV thingy.

Comment: @JonEricson, I've completely missed the link inside the image. Thanks! :facepalm:

Comment: Well, I clicked "Yes, this is correct" and I don't *think* I've merged my profile with his. It does say "tech **you** want to work with" though, so…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the report Jon. There were two problems here:

1. We shouldn't ever be showing the banner on public CVs. That's just weird.
2. When we do show banners we should only show them if you haven't already linked your account.

Both of these scenarios are now addressed.